# Managing state in Android app

Tags: java, android, state

Ive run into a problem with Android not letting you pass objects around Activities with intent' putExtra. So, if my application needs to make any number of network requests, it would make sense to keep futures in an object and get results as they become needed and block background threads if necessary.

How can you pass an object from one Activity to another without it being static or serialization?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. rephrase it

Comment: you can use Parceable in android for passing objects among activities

Comment: @Bali in that case say I have a future for a long running operation. I suspect that if I was to parcel (or serialize) said future, it would no longer be possible to retrieve the result.

Comment: Move the networking functions into service.

Comment: well then create a singleton Class for your response and use Gson library to  set and get data. from set and get i mean convert json string to java object and vice-versa

Comment: One way would be to use a Parcable to pass a object from one activity to another. It's a nice way to handle serialization for activities. Another way would be to store the data locally in the local database.

Comment: I think @ShadyAtef nailed it - looks like bound service is what Im looking for.